# Инициализация двумерного массива

Tags: массивы, c++

Про нициализация массива:

```
    const float table23 [25][10] = {
        {41.71,00.00,00.00,00.00,00.00,00.00,00.00,00.00,00.00,00.00},
        {43.97,43.74,43.52,43.29,43.07,42.84,42.61,42.39,42.16,41.94},
        {46.23,46.00,45.78,45.55,45.32,45.10,44.87,44.65,44.42,44.20},
        {48.48,48.26,48.03,47.81,47.58,47.36,47.13,46.90,46.68,46.45},
        {50.74,50.52,50.29,50.07,49.84,49.61,49.39,49.16,48.94,48.71},
        {53.00,52.77,52.55,52.32,52.10,51.87,51.65,51.42,51.19,50.97},
        {53.00,53.23,53.45,53.68,53.90,54.13,54.26,54.58,54.81,55.03},
        {55.26,55.48,55.71,55.94,56.16,56.39,56.61,56.84,57.06,57.29},
        {57.52,57.74,57.97,58.19,58.42,58.65,58.87,59.10,59.32,59.55},
        {59.77,60.00,60.23,60.45,60.68,60.90,61.13,61.35,61.58,61.81},
        {62.03,62.26,62.48,62.71,62.93,63.16,63.39,63.61,63.84,64.06},
        {64.29,64.52,64.74,64.97,65.19,65.43,65.64,65.87,66.10,66.32},
        {66.55,66.77,67.00,67.22,67.45,57.58,67.90,68.13,68.35,68.58},
        {68.81,69.03,69.26,69.48,69.71,69.93,70.16,70.39,70.61,70.84},
        {71.06,71.29,71.51,71.74,71.97,72.19,72.42,72.64,72.87,73.09},
        {73.32,73.655,73.77,74.0,74.22,74.45,74.68,74.90,75.13,75.13},
        {75,58,75,80,76,03,76,26,76,48,76,71,76,93,77,15,77,38,77,61},
        {77.84,78.06,78.29,78.51,78.74,78.97,79.19,79.42,79.64,79.87},
        {80.09,80.32,80.55,80.77,81.00,81.22,81.45,81.67,81.90,82.13},
        {82.35,82.58,82.80,83.06,83.26,83.48,83.71,83.93,84.16,84.38},
        {84.61,84.84,85.06,58.29,85.51,85.74,85.96,86.19,86.42,86.64},
        {86.87,87.09,87.32,87.54,87.77,88.00,88.22,88.45,88.67,88.90},
        {89.13,89.35,89.58,89.80,90.03,90.25,90.48,90.71,90.93,91.16},
        {91.38,91.61,91.83,92.06,92.29,92.51,92.74,92.96,93.18,93.42},
        {93.64,00.00,00.00,00.00,00.00,00.00,00.00,00.00,00.00,00.00}
};//39 строка
```

Появляется ошибка:

> too many initializers for ‘const float
> [10]’ metrology.cc    /metrology_part строка
> 39

Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 6):

В строке

```
{75,58,75,80,76,03,76,26,76,48,76,71,76,93,77,15,77,38,77,61},
```

вместо точек стоят запятые. Должно быть

```
{75.58,75.80,76.03,76.26,76.48,76.71,76.93,77.15,77.38,77.61},
```

Comment: Все верно, проворонил. Сто раз искал - не нашёл) Спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Очевидно, что в одном из ваших внутренних массивов элементов больше, чем 10. Пересчитывать элементы за вас не хотелось бы (да это и не самый лучший вариант), поэтому дам совет. Слышали о бинарном поиске? Удаляете из своего массива половину (ну хотя бы приблизительно), пытаетесь скомпилировать. Если  получится, значит проблема в той половине, которую вы удалили. Если не получится, значит в той, которая осталась. Найдя нужную половину, снова удаляете из нее половину вложенных массивов. И так до тех пор, пока не найдете нужный вложенный массив, содержащий ошибку. Сложность поиска логарифмическая, что существенно облегчает задачу

Comment: Приму к сведению. Совет дельный